# ValueError when doing data splitting for 6 datasets using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am attempting to do data splitting for 6 datasets using the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df4, df3, df1, df2, df5, df6 = make_blobs(n_samples=2000000)

df4_train, df4_test, df3_train, df3_test, df1_train, df1_test, df2_test, df2_train, df5_train, df5_test, df6_train, df6_test = train_test_split(df4, df3, test_size=0.30, random_state=10000, shuffle =True)

data_frames = [list() for x in range(6)]
```

However, it shows:

```
File "C:\Users\abd77\.spyder-py3\test_subject_1\data split.py", line 12, in <module>
    df4, df3, df1, df2, df5, df6 = make_blobs(n_samples=2000000)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem shows up at 4 where you are making the blobs.
Scikit-learn's make-blob method returns an X (input) and a y value (output). You can't just tell python to expect 6 different output values when the method returns 2.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html

To make 6 different datasets, you'll need to call make_blob 6 different times

```py
dfs = [make_blobs(n_samples=2000000) for i in range(6)]

dfs_split = [train_test_split(X,y) for X,y in dfs]
```

You can then access each X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test using:

```
##For the first df
X_train_df1 = dfs_split[0][0]
X_test_df1 = dfs_split[0][1]
y_train_df1 = dfs_split[0][2]
y_test_df1 = dfs_split[0][3]
```